# Integral and making a substitution over a given area

Tags: integration

If we have the integral

$\int x^2 * e^{-x^2}dx$

in the area where $x>0$. Now if we make the substitution $y = x^2$, why does the integral then become

$1/2\int y^{1/2} * e^{-y}$

as opposed to simply replacing all the $x^2$s with $y$s?

Comment: make the ansatz $\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx=(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^{-x}$ and differentiate this with respect to $x$

Comment: when you make the substitution $y = x^2$ $dy = 2xdx$ and $dx = \frac{1}{2y^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and the integral becomes $\int \frac{1}{2} y^{\frac{1}{2}}.e^ydy$

Answer (score 1):

If we say $y = x^2$ then $dy = 2 x dx$ and thus $dx = \frac{dy}{2 x} = \frac{dy}{2 y^{1/2}}$.

Thux $x^2 dx =  y \frac{dy}{2 y^{1/2}} =\frac{y^{1/2} dy}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because of the substitution for dx

In the integral you have

x^2*e^(-x^2)*dx

if you use:
y = x^2
dy = 2x*dx

The x in the dy expression requires that you cancel one of the x's in the integrand when substituting

x*e^-y*dy/2

and according to your substitution
x = y^(1/2)